# How would I find buttons and switches like would be found on old TVs and radios?

Tags: switches, components, button

I am working on a project that is attempting to emulate an old TV and radio. We need a rotary switch that has a very solid detent feel like those old TVs. We also would like to find a set of toggle buttons like you might have found in a car stereo in the 70s/80s. DigiKey has a [pretty vast](https://www.digikey.ca/products/en/switches/rotary-switches/200?FV=11400be%2C1140188%2C1140004%2C1140215%2Cffe000c8&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=0&rohs=0&k=rotary%20switch&quantity=5&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25&pkeyword=rotary%20switch) selection of rotary switches, but I'm not sure how to filter it down by feel other than ordering a bunch to test. I have no idea how to even search for the toggle-style buttons.

Any suggestions for how to find sets of switches/buttons that have the most appropriate feel?

P.S. We need to use components that are relatively easy to source as they will see a high amount of usage and will likely need to be replaced several times as they wear out, so scavenging from old equipment is not a very practical solution for us.

Comment: These are chosen by *technical specification*, not by *feel*. If you want the *feel*, you will need to order and try.

Comment: Junk yard or swap meet is your best bet.

Comment: @Passerby Hasn't OP ruled that out in his last sentence?

Comment: Rotary switches should have a rating for mechanical rotation torque on their datasheets.  Higher mechanical rotation = more solid "feel" in your case.  You can also look at specific toggle actuators - I think the ones you're looking for are "flatted".  Are the toggles push buttons or levers?

Comment: @Paul op is over estimating their usage and underestimating the life left in high quality mechanical switches vs modern day crap.

Comment: We can help, but.  By the absence of technical /electrical detail in your question, can I deduce that you're not an electronics engineer or student?  This will hamper your search and our assistance, so let's start with your editing the question with some background of your capabilities.  From past experience, I'm betting this is an arts based project.  True?

Comment: Rotary switches designed to switch power (120 VAC & 10 A or more) rather than signals are likely to have a more solid detent feel. Take something apart that has the toggle buttons and determine what is actuated by the buttons. It might be equivalent to something that is available.

Comment: From the source you linked, here is a series of switches that claim: “Distinctive Characteristics Positive detent mechanism for distinct feel and audible feedback.” http://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/MRpowerLevel.pdf

Comment: i too have strong feelings about the _feel_ of human interfaces, and i've basically just taken to ordering lots of candidates are re-ordering the nice ones in large quantities. i wish there was a better way, but i fear there's not.

Comment: @PaulUszak - I have a degree in computer engineering, but most of my experience has been in the software realm. This project is for a museum installation and needs to hold up to visitors turning the knob pretty much constantly for years. I'm still working with the stake holders to determine the technical requirements (number of detents, continuous vs stopped, etc) but they will be used to provide input to a microcontroller, so the electrical demands are low.

Comment: Okay, last comment.  You realise that you can amortize /spread the cost /effort and configure your installation with replaceable controls for when they wear out.  This also creates flexibility if you're unhappy with their tactile feel. Or you pay up front for industrial switch gear that lasts longer.  It's your call.

Comment: @CharlesCowie Thanks for pointing that switch out. The adjustability may also come in handy for our different stations with differing numbers of "channels" to switch between.